# Mp3 convert minutes into milliseconds

Tags: php

I'm making a websites with some audiofiles. 
So now I'm a bit stuck. 
I have to create a formula that converts f.ex; 3:11 into milliseconds. 
Should I use a while loop to do that?

```
<category id="cat2"/>
            <thumbnail url="admin/imgsupl/<? echo $row["thumbnail"]; ?>" />
            <pdf url="admin/docsupl/<? echo $row["filedownload"]; ?>" />
            <video url="admin/docsupl/alixir.flv" title="Alixir video"/>
            <?
            $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze("../admin/docsupl/".$row["voice_over_mp3"]);
            getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);
            $ThisFileInfo['playtime_string']; //3:11

            ?>
```

I can't manage to find an exact formula as well...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string by ":", and then you'll have minutes in one var and seconds in another. You then convert both of them to integers and multiply:

```
(minutes*60 + seconds) * 1000
```

Answer (score 4):

Converting should not be necessary. According to [this](http://www.getid3.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24), getID3 returns a `playtime_seconds` array element as well, counting the seconds. Then it's as easy as

```
$milliseconds =  $ThisFileInfo["playtime_seconds"] * 1000;
```